# Firefox plugin for html data

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am looking for FF plugin that display html of element in friendly popup on mousehover or click.
Do somebody know any?

Comment: I use firebug to show html and css in firefox if this is just what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I use firebug, but for edit css files in real time and I want to have quick access for id/classes of element on page. If I use only firebug I have to switch of displays too much and often

Comment: But this sounds quite a bit that you look for a visual editor, not for a plugin?

You can use Firbug as a new window, so there is no display switching.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) or [Web Developer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/). They both are very useful.

Web Developer has the advantage to be able to display information about the page inline, where as Firebug is more a console.